# Should I have an interface or class for my aggregate root?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Please see the code [here](https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/blob/master/DddInPractice.Logic/Common/AggregateRoot.cs) and specifically

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 

 namespace DddInPractice.Logic.Common 
 { 
     public abstract class AggregateRoot
     { 
         private readonly List<IDomainEvent> _domainEvents = new List<IDomainEvent>(); 
         public virtual IReadOnlyList<IDomainEvent> DomainEvents => _domainEvents; 


         protected virtual void AddDomainEvent(IDomainEvent newEvent) 
         { 
             _domainEvents.Add(newEvent); 
         } 


         public virtual void ClearEvents() 
         { 
             _domainEvents.Clear(); 
         } 
     } 
 }
```

I am debating whether to use this class in my project. I like the idea because it encapsulates Domain Events. If I use it then all Aggregate Root classes will derive from it. Alternatively, I could use a marker interface like this (which all Aggregate Roots will implement):

```
public interface IAggregateRoot
{
}
```

Should I:

1. Create the base class or
2. Create the interface or
3. Do neither?

I like the idea of marking my Aggregate Roots.

Comment: What purpose would the `interface IAggregateRoot` serve here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: "Should I eat an apple, a banana, or neither?" ;-)

Comment: Also, are you not offering us a false trichotomy here? What about `4) Create both`? `public abstract class AggregateRoot : IAggregateRoot { ...`

Comment: @David Arno, IAggregateRoot is just a marker interface.

Comment: @w0051977 It does **not** encapsulate domain events, it just contains them, there is a difference. "Contains" means it just has it inside it, while "Encapsulate" means it "contains" it *and* does not make it available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AggregateRoot`, like `Entity` and `Value`, is not (usually) part of the ubiquitous language of your domain.  It's really *metadata*, useful because it allows you to express domain knowledge in an domain agnostic way, so that your generic plumbing can do something useful with it.

As marker interface... well, to be honest, I don't see a lot of value add there.

As a role interface, it communicates the methods that must be implemented to act in the role.  This, as noted above, can make it easier to re-use plumbing code.

```
interface AggregateRoot {
    IReadOnlyList<IDomainEvent> changes();
    void clear();
}
```

And so you might have, for example

```
class HibernateCargo implements Cargo, AggregateRoot {
    // ...
}
```

You *can* use a base class here, but I find it's better to separate the contract from the implementation.

```
abstract class AggregateBase implements AggregateRoot {
    // ... 
}

class HibernateCargo extends AggregateBase, implements Cargo {
    // ...
}
```